# Querying ArcGIS file geodatabase from SQL?

Tags: sql-server, query, file-geodatabase

I need to compare data in a sql db with data stored in an arcgis file geodatabase. I'm not interested in the spatial attributes, only the added text attributes. What's the easiest way to do this?

I can get the data exported to csv. But I can see this exercise will be repeated. And it would really make my life easier if I could also update data to clean it up.

I believe we run arcgis 10.1 or 10.2.  I don't have arcgis desktop myself. Not sure if there are license limitations but installing it wouldn't be a problem.

I didn't want to influence the answer but I've been reading about gdal/ogr. And wonder if that's an option. Also I have no idea how hard it would be to install arcsde. And whether that could read/convert a fgdb on the fly.

Comment: You *can't* access a FGDB from *any* RDBMS directly, unless you want to spend a few weeks coding something in C++ with the FGDB API. CSV is likely your path of least resistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [ogrinfo](http://www.gdal.org/ogrinfo.html) which has the possibility to query every supported datasource with normal SQL-sytnax. The supported vector sources are documented [here](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_formats.html). This would give you the desired attributes.

In order to do a comparison with the features stored in the DB it would of course require some scripting or postprocessing.
If you don't mind e.g. using python and the [GDAL API](http://www.gdal.org/hierarchy.html) have a look at [the SQL-page](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html).

Comment: Will do thanks. Sorry would have voted up your answer but don't have enough points. :/